# Trigonometric transformation

Tags: trigonometry

$$\frac{1}{\sin^2 y}=3+\frac{1}{\cos^2 x}$$

Can we write $y$ as a simple function of $x$? I mean other than $\arcsin\left(3+\dfrac{1}{\cos^2 x}\right)^{-1/2}$?

Comment: Perhaps try to use the identity $\cos^2 x = 1 - \sin^2 x$?

Comment: I think just by looking at [a plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+1%2Fsin%28y%29^2+%3D+3%2B+1%2Fcos%28x%29^2) you can determine that the answer is no.

Comment: you can't even solve for $\sin(y)$, uniquely